# deprecated ’sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:' replacement

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Somebody knows how to use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: as a replacement of the deprecated ”sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:” method in this case.

```
CGSize labelSize = [self.mainLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.mainLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
```

Gets the warning: 'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

This is the hole code piece:

```
 // calculate the label size

CGSize labelSize = [self.mainLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.mainLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];

each_object(self.labels, ^(UILabel *label) {
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    frame.origin.x = offset;
    frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);
    frame.size.width = labelSize.width + 2.f /*Magic number*/;
    label.frame = frame;


    // Recenter label vertically within the scroll view
    label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x, roundf(self.center.y - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)));

    offset += CGRectGetWidth(label.bounds) + self.labelSpacing;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you have...

```
CGSize labelSize = [self.mainLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.mainLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
```

So use...

```
CGRect boundingRect = [self.mainLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))
                                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                        context:nil];

CGSize labelSize = boundingRect.size;
```

That should work.

Or... with attributes...

```
CGRect boundingRect = [self.mainLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))
                                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.mainLabel.font} 
                                                        context:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get this "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'boundingRectWithSize:options:context:'"

Comment: You can see it in the docs here... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Should I replace or should I put in somewhere where? Don't get clearer in the reference.

Comment: All this should do is replace the part where you're trying to get the size and use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

For example this way

```
-(CGFloat)getLabelSize:(UILabel *)label fontSize:(NSInteger)fontSize
{


   NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];

   CGRect frame = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(270, 2000.0)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:attributesDictionary
                                        context:nil];

   CGSize size = frame.size;

   return size.height;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I got some undeclared identifier on 'getLabelSize'. Sorry Im little of an newbie, how do I fix this?

Comment: How did you call this method and where?

Comment: From the InfoViewController.m

Comment: I mean from the InfoViewController.h '#import "CBAutoScrollLabel.h"' '@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScrollLabel;
'

Comment: Did you add the method getLabelSize to view controller? Use (CBAutoScrollLabel *)label in method call instead of UILabel

Comment: What is this 'getLabelSize'? - now it's an undeclared identifier. I don't get it?!

Comment: Im not sure of how to add 'getLabelSize' with right syntax to, in this case InfoViewController.h